# APK generated by github python to android action crashing

Tags: python, android, github, github-actions

I created apk using python to android action on github for my repo https://github.com/sameermahajan/Paadas (you can check my workflow yml as well as buildozer spec there). The apk is generated correctly without any error however when I download, install and run it on my mobile phone(s) it exits / crashes soon after opening the screen and stating "Loading..." What am I missing?

I even tried a simple 'Hello Android!' program (https://github.com/sameermahajan/hello-android) which runs into the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `kivy`, but none of your python code creates a kivy app object, which is needed for this to work. See [Kivy Basics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html) for more info, including a 'hello-world' style example of a Kivy app.

Additionally, you'll probably also need to use [kivy audio](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html) instead of `playsound`.

Comment: I updated my https://github.com/sameermahajan/hello-android as per kivy basics but still see the same crash :( Or is the app exiting now?

Comment: I uninstalled my old app, then downloaded and installed this new app that worked! Will try now with my original app.

Comment: I got my original app working now on android with kivy. However is there a way to get bare bone python working on android (may be by some other actions / means)?